# Labels next to dots in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often draw a tikz diagram where I specify the nodes and the label separately:

```
\tikzset{%
  dot/.style={circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt},
  top/.style={anchor=south, inner sep=5pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[dot] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[top] at (A) {label};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works perfectly fine, but it feels like it can be written more consisely, like:

```
\node[dot-top] (A) at (0,0) {label};
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Maybe like this? `\node[dot,label={[top]90:label}] (A) at (0,0) {};`

Comment: Well, if I then want to have some of the labels display top, some left, etc, I also need to change the number 90 to 180, etc. every time, so although it is more concisely written in a single line, it looks less adaptable than using two nodes (or at least more of a hassle).

Comment: You can put the definition in your `dot` and use `dot=...` to change the defaults. That's why pgfkeys exist

Comment: @percusse Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Something like this is good enough? `\node[dot,label=above:label] (A) at (0,0) {};`