# Trying to put bullet on top lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a bunch of straight lines, I just want to put big bullets at any place (say at the end points)  and of consecutive colors (red, blue, red, blue). I am trying but not able to get any help from the web.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

     \draw (0,0) -- (0,4);
     \draw (0.3,0) -- (0.3,4);
     \draw (0.8,0) -- (0.8,4);
     \draw (1.1,0) -- (1.1,4);
     \draw (1.6,0) -- (1.6,4);
     \draw (1.9,0) -- (1.9,4);
     \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:18.5,-0.019){\textbullet};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is my failed attempt

Comment: There is the command `\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (3pt);` for example.

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429846/14757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Filled circles

The example names the endpoints as `1bot` to `6bot` and `1top` to `6top` to make it easier to color them independent from the actual coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
      \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0, 0.3, 0.8, 1.1, 1.6, 1.9} {
        (\x, 0) coordinate (\i bot) -- (\x, 4) coordinate (\i top)
      }
    ;
    \fill[red, radius=2pt]
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 6} {
        (\i bot) circle[]
      }
    ;
    \fill[blue, radius=2pt]
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 6} {
        (\i top) circle[]
      }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Plot marks

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
      \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0, 0.3, 0.8, 1.1, 1.6, 1.9} {
        (\x, 0) coordinate (\i bot) -- (\x, 4) coordinate (\i top)
      }
    ;
    \path plot[mark=*, mark options=red] coordinates {
      (1bot) (2top) (3bot) (4top) (5bot) (6top)
    };
    \path plot[mark=*, mark options=blue] coordinates {
      (1top) (2bot) (3top) (4bot) (5top) (6bot)
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also, the lines can be colored (as requested by the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429853/trying-to-put-bullet-on-top-lines/429855?noredirect=1#comment1090049_429855)):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red]
      \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0, 0.8, 1.6} {
        (\x, 0) coordinate (r\i bot) -- (\x, 4) coordinate (r\i top)
      }
    ;
    \draw[blue]
      \foreach[count=\i] \x in {0.3, 1.1, 1.9} {
        (\x, 0) coordinate (b\i bot) -- (\x, 4) coordinate (b\i top)
      }
    ;
    \path plot[mark=*, mark options=red] coordinates {
      (r1bot) (b1top) (r2bot) (b2top) (r3bot) (b3top)
    };
    \path plot[mark=*, mark options=blue] coordinates {
      (r1top) (b1bot) (r2top) (b2bot) (r3top) (b3bot)
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with colored lines]

Comment: I am so sorry. just a last inconvenience, is there a way to color these straight lines depending on the color at the bottom? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Shamina See updated answer.